# Reorder of the words inside sublists of a bigger list with R

Tags: r, list

Hello I have this list which includes other lists.

```
LIST <- list(list(c("USA","DC","MD","Washigton","Baltimore", 'Russia')), 
                list(c("USA","DC","MD","TX","Washigton","Baltimore","Dallas",'Russia',"France")), 
                list(c("USA","DC","MD","TX","Washigton","Baltimore","Dallas")),
                list(c("USA","DC","MD","TX","Washigton","Baltimore","Dallas",'Russia' )),
                list(c("USA","DC","Washigton")),
                list(c("USA","DC","Washigton","France")))
```

My goal is to display it in this form: "DC","Washigton","MD","Baltimore", "Russia" which means that the city should follow the state and if there is another country/ies should be displayed last. At this point I have achieved this:

```
output <- list()
for(i in 1:length(LIST)){
  country  <- sort( unique( LIST[[i]][[1]][ !sapply(LIST[[i]][[1]], function(y){foo(y)})  ] ))
  USAcheck <- any( country %in% 'USA')
  country  <- country[! country %in% 'USA']
  state    <- sort( unique( LIST[[i]][[1]][ sapply(LIST[[i]][[1]], function(y){foo(y)})  ] ))


  if(USAcheck){

    if( length(state) > 0){
      myString <- 'USA ('

      for(j in 1:length(state)){
        if(j == length(state)){
          myString <- paste0(myString, state[j], "), ")
        }else{
          myString <- paste0(myString, state[j], ", ")

        }
      }
    }else{
      myString <- 'USA, '
    }



  }else{
    myString <- ''
  }



  for(j in 1:length(country)){

    if(j == length(country)){
      myString <- paste0(myString, country[j])
    }else{
      myString <- paste0(myString, country[j], ", ")
    }

  }
  output[[i]] <- list( myString )

}
```

and took this result:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "DC, MD Baltimore, Russia, Washigton"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "DC, MD, TX Baltimore, Dallas, France, Russia, Washigton"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "DC, MD, TX Baltimore, Dallas, Washigton"


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] "DC, MD, TX Baltimore, Dallas, Russia, Washigton"


[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] "DC Washigton"


[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
[1] "DC France, Washigton"
```

A Hint that may help is that in my initial list states and cities match in the way that if for example I have "DC","MD","Washigton","Baltimore" "DC" matches with " Washington" and "MD" with "Baltimore". It is like first word matching with third and second with fourth. Here "DC","MD","TX","Washigton","Baltimore","Dallas" it is again the same logic. If there is no generic way that this can e achieved I wold like to be able to change this order "manually" in every sublist.
Any advice?

This is how my original list looks like:

```
> output
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "Argentina" "Brazil"    "Colombia"  "Mexico"   


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "Australia" "India"    


[[3]]
[1] "DC, MD, Washington, Baltimore"

[[4]]
[1] "MA, Boston"

[[5]]
[1] "CO, Aurora"

[[6]]
[1] "MA, Boston"

[[7]]
[[7]][[1]]
[1] "Belgium"


[[8]]
[[8]][[1]]
[1] "Belgium" "Italy"   "UK"     


[[9]]
[1] "USA (AL, AZ, CA, CO, CT, DC, DE, FL, GA, IA, IL, IN, KY, LA, MA, MD, ME, MI, MN, MO, NC, ND, NE, NH, NJ, NM, NY, OH, OK, OR, PA, RI, SC, SD, TN, TX, UT, VA, WI, WV), Australia, Canada, Israel, Korea, Mexico, Switzerland, Taiwan"

[[10]]
[[10]][[1]]
[1] NA


[[11]]
[1] "MA, Boston"

[[12]]
[1] "MA, WA, Boston, Seattle, France"

[[13]]
[[13]][[1]]
[1] "Canada"


[[14]]
[[14]][[1]]
[1] "China"


[[15]]
[1] "MA, TN, Boston, Nashville"

[[16]]
[[16]][[1]]
[1] "Denmark"


[[17]]
[1] "USA (NH, NJ, NM, NY) "

[[18]]
[1] "USA (CA, DC, IL, IN, MA, MD, MI, TN, TX) "

[[19]]
[1] "USA (AL, CA, NH, NJ, NM, NY, TN) "

[[20]]
[1] "USA (CA, IN, MA, NH, NJ, NM, NY, PA) "

[[21]]
[[21]][[1]]
[1] "Canada"


[[22]]
[[22]][[1]]
[1] NA


[[23]]
[1] "USA (CA, CT, MA, MO, NC, ND, NH, NJ, NM, NY, OH, TN, WA), Korea, Netherlands, Spain"

[[24]]
[[24]][[1]]
[1] "Sweden"


[[25]]
[1] "TX, Dallas"
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be one approach - just seeing which state-city pair is in there and indexing it. And then appending all the remaining items

```
LIST <- list(list(c("USA","DC","MD","Washigton","Baltimore", 'Russia')), 
             list(c("USA","DC","MD","TX","Washigton","Baltimore","Dallas",'Russia',"France")), 
             list(c("USA","DC","MD","TX","Washigton","Baltimore","Dallas")),
             list(c("USA","DC","MD","TX","Washigton","Baltimore","Dallas",'Russia' )),
             list(c("USA","DC","Washigton")),
             list(c("USA","DC","Washigton","France")))  

locations <- rbind(states = c("DC", "MD", "TX"),
                   cities = c("Washigton", "Baltimore", "Dallas")
                   )

lapply(LIST, function(x) {
  lapply(x, function(y) {
    c(as.vector(
      locations[, colSums(rbind(locations[1, ] %in% y,
                                locations[2, ] %in% y)) == 2]), y[!y%in%locations])
  })
})


[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "DC"        "Washigton" "MD"        "Baltimore" "USA"       "Russia"   


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "DC"        "Washigton" "MD"        "Baltimore" "TX"        "Dallas"    "USA"       "Russia"    "France"   


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "DC"        "Washigton" "MD"        "Baltimore" "TX"        "Dallas"    "USA"      


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] "DC"        "Washigton" "MD"        "Baltimore" "TX"        "Dallas"    "USA"       "Russia"   


[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] "DC"        "Washigton" "USA"      


[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
[1] "DC"        "Washigton" "USA"       "France"
```

Comment: This is certainly a way but I have a long list in which I have to apply it with many options in cities and states.

Comment: Are states always 2 letters long?

Comment: It would be ideal if I could achieve this while creating the list (inside the if) and not after creating it but i ll wait for your solution.

Comment: Where is your data coming from, then? Hard to say how to do it in the creation process otherwise. Either way, I don't think there is any way around having a matrix that indicates which state belongs to which capital -

Comment: I understand, if there is not a generic solution then I have to work on each list separatedly. Could you show me how I could achieve this by reordering-lets say-the 1st list?

Comment: I edited the question to show you how my original list looks like